# Expand Variadic Template Pack by Pairs

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, sfinae, template-argument-deduction

I'm creating a generic collection of `Node`s. Each `Node` has a `Start` and `End` type. And the `End` type of one must match the `Start` type of the next.

If I were to list each of the types in the collection the constructor would look like this (for four types):

```
template <typename Start, typename End>
class Node {
};

template <typename A, typename B, typename C, typename D>
class Collection
{
public:
    Collection(Node<A, B> n1, Node<B, C> n2, Node<C, D> n3) { }
};
```

But when I try to write constuctor as a variadic template to support any number of types, I am stumped.

Comment: It would be great to show your attempt at writing a contructor with variadic template. We may be able to not only help, but also analyze your thought process and point where exactly the logic you came up with was flawed.

Comment: Can you use C++17?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose a little different solution.

Given a trivial `tag` struct to wrap a generic type (to avoid problems with types not default constructible in `std::tuples`s)

```
template <typename>
struct tag
 { };
```

and an helper struct that define 2 types based on `std::tuple`

```
template <typename...>
struct getTpls;

template <std::size_t ... Is, typename ... Ts>
struct getTpls<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts...>
 {
   using tpl0 = std::tuple<tag<Ts>...>;
   using ftpl = std::tuple<std::tuple_element_t<Is,    tpl0>...>;
   using stpl = std::tuple<std::tuple_element_t<1u+Is, tpl0>...>;
 };
```

you can write `Collection` as follows

```
template <typename ... Ts>
struct Collection
 {
   static_assert( sizeof...(Ts) > 1u, "more types, please");

   using getT = getTpls<std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)-1u>, Ts...>;

   using ftpl = typename getT::ftpl;
   using stpl = typename getT::stpl;

   template <typename ... FTs, typename ... STs,
             std::enable_if_t<
                 std::is_same_v<ftpl, std::tuple<tag<FTs>...>>
              && std::is_same_v<stpl, std::tuple<tag<STs>...>>, int> = 0>
   Collection (Node<FTs, STs> ...)
    { }
 };
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Start, typename End>
class Node
 { };

struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C {};

template <typename>
struct tag
 { };

template <typename...>
struct getTpls;

template <std::size_t ... Is, typename ... Ts>
struct getTpls<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts...>
 {
   using tpl0 = std::tuple<tag<Ts>...>;
   using ftpl = std::tuple<std::tuple_element_t<Is,    tpl0>...>;
   using stpl = std::tuple<std::tuple_element_t<1u+Is, tpl0>...>;
 };

template <typename ... Ts>
struct Collection
 {
   static_assert( sizeof...(Ts) > 1u, "more types, please");

   using getT = getTpls<std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)-1u>, Ts...>;

   using ftpl = typename getT::ftpl;
   using stpl = typename getT::stpl;

   template <typename ... FTs, typename ... STs,
             std::enable_if_t<
                 std::is_same_v<ftpl, std::tuple<tag<FTs>...>>
              && std::is_same_v<stpl, std::tuple<tag<STs>...>>, int> = 0>
   Collection (Node<FTs, STs> ...)
    { }
 };

int main ()
 {
   Collection<A, B, C>  c0{Node<A, B>{}, Node<B, C>{}};    // compile
   // Collection<A, B, B>  c1{Node<A, B>{}, Node<B, C>{}}; // error!
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I like how your answer leaves the constructor looking most like the intended data that fills it. I don't think templates should ever obfuscate the intent of the function.

Comment: The part that I was missing in my code was how to infer the types FTs and STs. I didn't realize you could use enable_if to do that.

Answer (score 1):

With some indirection, you might do:

```
template <typename Start, typename End>
class Node {
    // ...
};

// Implementation using the Nodes
// You might add typedef in Node to retrieve Start/End if needed (or create traits)
template <typename ... Nodes>
struct CollectionImpl
{
    CollectionImpl(Nodes ... ns) : nodes(ns...){}

    std::tuple<Nodes...> nodes; // You probably want something like that
};

// Helper class to build the type
template <typename Seq, typename Tup> struct CollectionMaker;

template <std::size_t ... Is, typename Tuple>
struct CollectionMaker<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Tuple>
{
    using type = CollectionImpl<Node<std::tuple_element_t<Is, Tuple>,
                                     std::tuple_element_t<Is + 1, Tuple>>...>;
};

// Wanted interface.
template <typename ... Ts>
using Collection = typename CollectionMaker<std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts) - 1>,
                                            std::tuple<Ts...>>::type;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/kLIwBk)

Answer (score 1):

Based on max66's answer:

This cleans up the unnecessary `tag` structure and simplifies the `index_sequence` to direct recursion (similar to the definition of tuple).

```
template <typename Owner, typename Value>
class Node {
};


struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C {};
struct D {};


template <typename First, typename...Rest>
std::tuple<First, Rest...> tuple_push_front(std::tuple<Rest...>);

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename...T>
struct NodeCollector {
private:
    using nodeRest = NodeCollector<T2, T...>;
public:
    using tplOwners = decltype(tuple_push_front<T1>(std::declval<typename nodeRest::tplOwners>()));
    using tplValues = decltype(tuple_push_front<T2>(std::declval<typename nodeRest::tplValues>()));
};
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct NodeCollector<T1, T2> {
public:
    using tplOwners = std::tuple<T1>;
    using tplValues = std::tuple<T2>;
};


template <typename...Ts>
class Collection
{
    static_assert( sizeof...(Ts) > 1u, "Collection requires at least two types.");
private:
    using nodeCollector = NodeCollector<Ts...>;
public:
    template <typename...OTs, typename...VTs, typename=std::enable_if_t<
        (std::is_same_v<typename nodeCollector::tplOwners, std::tuple<OTs...>> &&
         std::is_same_v<typename nodeCollector::tplValues, std::tuple<VTs...>>)> >
    Collection(Node<OTs, VTs>...) { }
};


int main()
{
    Collection<A, B, C, D> c{Node<A, B>{}, Node<B, C>{}, Node<C, D>{}};
    std::cout << demangle(typeid(c).name()) << std::endl;
}
```